# SQL Server trigger and bulk updates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following trigger in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_UpdateSearch 
    ON nt_CadProduct  
    FOR  UPDATE
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CodProduct INT
    SET @CodProduct = (SELECT prdCod FROM INSERTED)

    DECLARE @DescSearch VARCHAR(500)
    SET @DescSearch = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),p.prdCod) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),p.prdDesc) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),p.prdCaract) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),p.prdCodFab) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),f.fabname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),g.grpName)  +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),a.agrpname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),t.tpName) 
                       FROM nt_CadProduct AS p 
                       LEFT JOIN nt_cadFab AS f ON p.prdFab = f.fabcod 
                       LEFT JOIN nt_CadGp AS g ON p.prdGp = g.grpCod 
                       LEFT JOIN nt_cadagp AS a ON p.prdagp = a.agpcod 
                       LEFT JOIN nt_CadT AS t ON p.prdTb = t.tpCod 
                       WHERE prdCod = @CodProduct)

    UPDATE Index_nt_CadProduct
    SET IndexSearch = @DescSearch 
    WHERE IdProduct = @CodProduct

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO Index_nt_CadProduct (IdProduct, IndexSearch) 
        VALUES (@CodProduct, @DescSearch)
END
```

It is working fine for single updates but if I try bulk updates it doesn’t work because the subquery returns more than 1 value, I have tried to use JOIN INSERTED instead of using DECLARE but it doesn’t work either.

I have tried several "solutions" from other SO answers with no success because of the need I have to perform the `@DescSearch` query to return the concat result

I have changed the name of the columns, so if there is any misspells just ignore it. The actual trigger is functional

Comment: A common beginner mistake.   Instead of populating variables you should use JOINs to Inserted/Deleted so that your trigger handles all rows.   I'm sure this question is already duplicated several times on StackOverflow.

Comment: Like I said I have tried using JOINS to INSERTED too but get same error. I think the problem is somewhere in the DECLARE DescSearch query where I use the DECLARE CodProduct to concat the columns. I have tried SELECT i.prdCod FROM INSERTED i instead of using DECLARE CodProduct

Comment: in your nested select, you've got a lot of left joins and your where is `WHERE prdCod = @CodProduct`  but you didn't qualify `prdCod` ... what table is that from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this without a temp table. I'm not 100% on the joins you've got there - did my best to parse it all out. I think it should work, though, for multiple records. Give it a **test**.

```
BEGIN
       UPDATE Index_nt_CadProduct
          SET IndexSearch = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),nt_CadProduct.prdCod) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),nt_CadProduct.prdDesc) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),nt_CadProduct.prdCaract) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),nt_CadProduct.prdCodFab) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),f.fabname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),g.grpName)  +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),a.agrpname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),t.tpName)
         FROM INSERTED
         JOIN Index_nt_CadProduct
           ON Index_nt_CadProduct.IdProduct = INSERTED.prdCod
         JOIN nt_CadProduct
           ON nt_CadProduct.prdCod = Index_nt_CadProduct.IdProduct
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadFab AS f ON nt_CadProduct.prdFab = f.fabcod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadGp AS g ON nt_CadProduct.prdGp = g.grpCod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadagp AS a ON nt_CadProduct.prdagp = a.agpcod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadT AS t ON nt_CadProduct.prdTb = t.tpCod 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO Index_nt_CadProduct (IdProduct, IndexSearch)
        SELECT INSERTED.prdCod
             , CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),nt_CadProduct.prdCod) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),nt_CadProduct.prdDesc) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),nt_CadProduct.prdCaract) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),nt_CadProduct.prdCodFab) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),f.fabname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),g.grpName)  +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),a.agrpname) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),t.tpName)
         FROM INSERTED
         JOIN Index_nt_CadProduct
           ON Index_nt_CadProduct.IdProduct = INSERTED.prdCod
         JOIN nt_CadProduct
           ON nt_CadProduct.prdCod = Index_nt_CadProduct.IdProduct
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadFab AS f ON nt_CadProduct.prdFab = f.fabcod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadGp AS g ON nt_CadProduct.prdGp = g.grpCod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadagp AS a ON nt_CadProduct.prdagp = a.agpcod 
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadT AS t ON nt_CadProduct.prdTb = t.tpCod 

END
```

... though it occurs to me that the long concatenated string would be null if any of those `LEFT JOIN`s were null.

Comment: The solution with the temp table is working but I'm worried about performance, don't really know about impact on that, your solution on the other hand throws me an error recovering the INSERTED.prdCod, I also Added some ( ) around both selects since was throwing syntax error too... about the null part you were right, but I solved that using COALESCE, I would love to make it work without the temp table

Comment: You shouldn't need the additional ()

Comment: Awesome, just one more detail, the ROWCOUNT = 0 is not working, it only updates but does not insert, do you know how I can debug that? thank you

Comment: nevermind, jus edited your code and fixed the problem, there was a JOIN in the insert that wasnt supposed to be there, just some copy paste mistake ;) Thank you, now is working 100%

Comment: This wouldn't work for inserts if there are any updates in inserted rows, no? That was the reason that I opted a temp table. Instead of a temp table you could declare and insert into a table variable.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the data it is sort of hard, maybe this is what you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_UpdateSearch ON nt_CadProduct
  FOR UPDATE
AS
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT  distinct p.prdCod,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), p.prdCod) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), p.prdDesc) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), p.prdCaract) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), p.prdCodFab) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), f.fabname) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), g.grpName) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), a.agrpname) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), t.tpName) AS descSearch
    INTO    #tmp
    FROM    nt_CadProduct AS p
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadFab AS f ON p.prdFab = f.fabcod
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadGp AS g ON p.prdGp = g.grpCod
    LEFT JOIN nt_cadagp AS a ON p.prdagp = a.agpcod
    LEFT JOIN nt_CadT AS t ON p.prdTb = t.tpCod
    WHERE   prdCod IN ( SELECT  prdCod
                        FROM    inserted );

    WITH  x AS (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   [#tmp] AS [t]
                 WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                 FROM   Index_nt_CadProduct inp
                                 WHERE  t.prdCod = inp.IdProduct )
               )
      UPDATE  Index_nt_CadProduct
      SET     IndexSearch = x.descSearch
      FROM    x
      WHERE   IdProduct = x.prdCod;

    INSERT  INTO Index_nt_CadProduct ( IdProduct, IndexSearch )
    SELECT  prdCod, descSearch
    FROM    [#tmp] AS [t]
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   Index_nt_CadProduct inp
                         WHERE  t.prdCod = inp.IdProduct );
    drop table #tmp;
  END;
```